# Does spring REST support look up by resourceid which starts with period /resources/{resourceid}

Tags: spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-web

I am working on REST api which has lookup by resourceid and resourceid starts with . or / or //. I am able to handle cases where it starts with / or contains / but not resources whos identifiers start with . eg: /resources/.ABC-A
Im looking some solutions on how to handle cases whose resource id starts with .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `.` is allowed at the start of the path. Per RFC 3896:

> The path segments "." and "..", also known as dot-segments, are
>      defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.  They
>      are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference
>      (Section 4.2) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical
>      tree of names.  This is similar to their role within some operating
>      systems' file directory structures to indicate the current directory
>      and parent directory, respectively.  However, unlike in a file
>      system, these dot-segments are only interpreted within the URI path
>      hierarchy and are removed as part of the resolution process (Section
>      5.2).

Also, a word of caution when using `.` in your paths: by default Spring will try and use the path to determine content type:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Example: A path ending in `.au` can be interpreted as a request for `application/audio`, for which you probably don't have a handler installed.

To disable this behavior you would set `favorPathExtension=false` on your `ContentNegotiationConfigurer`.